# Bash script that reads rsync progress and bails on the file if too slow

Tags: bash, rsync

I have so little experience with bash scripting that it is laughable.

I have spent 3 days transferring files from a failing HDD (1 of 3 in an LVM) on my NAS to a new HDD. Most (percentage wise) of the files transfer fine, but many (thousands) are affected and instead of failing with an i/o error, they drop the speed down to agonizing rates.

I was using a simple cp command but then I switched to rsync and used the --progress option to at least be able to identify when this was happening.

Currently, I'm manually watching the screen (sucks when we're talking DAYS), ^C when there's a hangup, then copy the file name and paste it into an exclude file and restart rsync.

I *NEED* to automate this!

I know nothing about bash scripting, but I figure I can probably "watch" the standard output, parse the rate info and use some logic like this:

```
if rate is less than 5Mbps for 3 consecutive seconds, bail and restart
```

This is the rsync command I'm using:
    rsync -aP --ignore-existing --exclude-from=EXCLUDE /mnt/olddisk/ /mnt/newdisk/

And here is a sample output from progress:

```
path/to/file.ext
    3434,343,343 54%  144.61MB/s   0:00:05 (xfr#1, ir-chk=1024/1405)
```

So parse the 3rd column of the 2nd line and make sure it isn't too slow, if it is then kill the command, append the file name to EXCLUDE and give it another go.

Is that something someone can help me with?

Comment: That's not the only way to address the problem -- you could also give `rsync -e` a command that detects when the pipeline has stalled. If it's ssh (the default transport), and it's stalling out *completely*, it might just be a matter of adding a few timeout options (yes, ssh has built-in support for killing idle connections).

Comment: On the client side, f/e, you can set `ServerAliveInterval`

Comment: ...as an entirely different approach, you could also insert a separate program in the pipeline that monitors transfer speed and does the cutoff from this position in the middle. Look at [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) for an example of a tool built to sit in the middle of a pipeline and monitor traffic; no reason you couldn't throw together something to do the same and die if it hasn't seen a certain amount of traffic in a given amount of time (though bash's the wrong language to use for a performance-sensitive tool of that type).

Comment: To be clear, I think watching the progress bar is a particularly *bad* way to solve the problem -- it's designed for human consumption, not programmatic use, so its format is liable to change without notice between versions.

Comment: Also, frankly, there are much better ways to transfer data off a failing drive. Using `dd_rescue` to make a byte-for-byte image on working media is where I'd start -- that way you get literally every possible byte of recoverable data, and can fix up parts that weren't referenced due to filesystem breakage &c. later.

Comment: ...which is to say -- the more I think about this, the more certain I am that rsync is the wrong tool to start with, that this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) question, and that you should be asking about data recovery techniques (not rsync restart automation!) over on [unix.se].

Comment: ...btw, see also https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html

Comment: Charles, I appreciate the comments.  I started with dd_rescue, but after 14 hours it showed 0.00% completed.  I searched for half a day on that problem and got no useful solutions.  This really isn't a data recovery problem - from my perspective - because the data isn't lost.  I have backups on a remote server.  But I also have bandwidth constraints to consider.  I want to get the bulk of the 12TB locally and then recover what is missing remotely.  And for the most part, this is almost working... it just gets stuck.  It is that "stuck" I'm trying to solve, even if there is a "right" way.

Comment: And "stuck" isn't the right word.  Nothing (yet) has actually failed.  It just runs extremely slow for certain files (or parts of files).  I'm looking for a quick & dirty "solution" to get through this ASAP.

Comment: Amusing link about XY Problems.  The argument is logically flawed, and starts with the assumption that the helper knows more about everything than the helpee.  There are often a multitude of constraints that aren't practical (or in some cases legal) to convey.  Sometimes... people just need answers to the questions they asked, despite how certain others are that it was the wrong question.  I'm *not* saying that's the case here... although I did spend many hours searching out the "right" way, and I'm settling on what's (sort of) working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a horrible approach, and I do not expect it to usefully solve your problem. However, the following is a literal answer to your question.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
[[ $1 ]] || {
  echo "Usage: rsync -P --exclude=exclude-file ... | $0 exclude-file" >&2
  exit 1
}

is_too_slow() {
  local rate=$1
  case $rate in
    *kB/s)          return 0 ;;
    [0-4][.]*MB/s)  return 0 ;;
    *)              return 1 ;;
  esac
}

exclude_file=$1
last_slow_time=0

filename=
too_slow_count=0
while IFS=$'\n' read -r -d $'\r' -a pieces; do
  for piece in "${pieces[@]}"; do
    case $piece in
      "sending incremental file list") continue ;;
      [[:space:]]*)
        read -r size pct rate time <<<"$piece"
        if is_too_slow "$rate"; then
          if (( last_slow_time == SECONDS )); then
            continue # ignore multiple slow results in less than a second
          fi
          last_slow_time=$SECONDS
          if (( ++too_slow_count > 3 )); then
            echo "$filename" >>"$exclude_file"
            exit 1
          fi
        else
          too_slow_count=0
        fi
        ;;
      *) filename=$piece; too_slow_count=0 ;;
    esac
  done
done
```

Comment: You end the old year on a clever note Charles `:)`

Comment: Thanks!  I completely appreciate your disdain for my approach.  I equally appreciate your compliance!  Having virtually no knowledge of this language, and doing my best to interpret what you have, I'm not seeing any mechanism for checking "for 3 consecutive seconds".  I see the ++too_slow_count > 3 line and I'm guessing that's it... but I'm not seeing what defines that as seconds and not cycles?  I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: Right -- original code assumed rsync updated the progress bar once per second. If you wanted to ensure that we ignore multiple results received within the same second, you can check the `SECONDS` variable and ignore consecutive results where it matches. See edits implementing that.

Comment: Oh, I see.  It wasn't important then... I erroneously thought it was more realtime than that.  I didn't realize your script was refreshing with each update, but each cpu cycle. [if you read the rest of this before I edited... I figured it out]

Comment: Didn't quite work.  So I type the following:  rsync -aP --ignore-existing --exclude-from=EXCLUDE /mnt/olddisk/ /mnt/newdisk/ | ./script.sh EXCLUDE

Then I get no feedback (expected) but something is happening.  I run a few sequential du -s and I can see the directory growing at a very slow rate.  It appears to be doing exactly the same as before?  It doesn't seem to be catching that the rate is very low.  When I run the command again (without piping to the script) I see it transfering at roughly 35kB/s

Comment: Well isn't luck and timing funny!  I went back to doing things manually (gotta get it done!) and I skipped the first choked on file, then the 2nd.... then it started rocketing through!  2TB down.  Here's hoping it continues.  If it can even get close to the end, I'm way further ahead.  Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: `PS4=':$LINENO+' bash -x ./script.sh EXCLUDE` should collect logs sufficient to allow debugging, if we get back to where we need to dig into why it didn't trigger. I wouldn't be surprised if the `is_too_slow` function's traces were all we needed to look at, if that's returning the wrong result.